# App indexing does not show image or results based on email/phone search

Tags: android, firebase, android-app-indexing

I was following: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/app-indexing/

to index app only content

```
private void indexAll(ArrayList<User> users) {
    ArrayList<Indexable> indexablePersons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : users) {
        PersonBuilder personBuilder = Indexables.personBuilder();
        personBuilder.setUrl("https://www.xxxx.com/user/?user_id=" + user.id);
        personBuilder.setName(user.name);
        personBuilder.setEmail(user.email);
        personBuilder.setTelephone(user.phone);
        personBuilder.setDescription(user.description);
        personBuilder.setImage("https://www.xxxx.com/image/user/" + user.id);

        indexablePersons.add(personBuilder.build());
    }

    if (indexablePersons.size() > 0) {
        Indexable[] personsArr = new Indexable[indexablePersons.size()];
        personsArr = indexablePersons.toArray(personsArr);

        FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(personsArr);
    }
}
```

> Now when I search from the google app on the device - It only works
>   for the name. If I search using email/phone/description it doesn't
>   show results.
>
> Also the image shown in the search result when I search by name is the
>   app icon, not the actual image I set using `setImage`

[image]